# How can I select data from a postgresdb and insert into an elasticsearch index?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, elasticsearch, sinatra

Using sinatra, postgres and the elasticsearch gem, I would like to select data form the database, convert it into json, on the fly, and then put it to an elasticsearch index, i.e. create an index with the records just selected.

The ruby code is:

```
get '/send_data_to_elastic' do
 result = DB[:candidates].map do |r|
  { :first => r[:first], :last => r[:last], :email => r[:email], :company => r[:company] }
end
 client = Elasticsearch::Client.new log: true
 #client.delete  index: 'mycandidates', type: 'mykind', id: 3
 #client.index  index: 'candidates', type: 'mykind', id: 12, body: {data:'data'}
 client.index  index: 'candidates', type: 'mykind', id: 12, body: result.to_json
end
```

This does not work and I get the following error:

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest at /send_data_to_elastic
[400] {"error":"MapperParsingException[failed to parse]; nested: ElasticSearchParseException[Failed to derive xcontent from (offset=0, length=4): [110, 117, 108, 108]]; ","status":400}
```

Any ideas guys? Am I attempting the impossible or going about it the wrong way? All help, as usual, gratefully received.

Comment: I think this is ruby related. Check how you create JSON documents in ruby. After that there should be nothing blocking you from indexing this in ElasticSearch.